# How to change a element/tag value by its attribute value?

Tags: xml, xslt, treeview, xslt-1.0

I have a XML code with a long list of  tags, and I want to replace in every element "text" the words inside  and  tags by their respective "form" attribute value.

For example, here's 2 sentences from my XML file:

```
<messages>
    <text>
        <spelling form="Hello">Helo</spelling> I'll see you next <abrev form="week">wk</abrev> alright.
    </text>
    <text>
        <abrev form="Come on">cmon</abrev> get ready <spelling form="dude">dood</spelling>!
    </text>
</messages>
```

Here's the output I'm looking for:

```
Hello I'll see you next week alright.
Come on get ready dude!
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

---

Here is what I have so far in my XSL file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:for-each select="messages/text">

        <xsl:call-template name="parse">

            <!-- this selects all the tags inside "text" (I think...) -->
            <xsl:with-param name="a" select="./*"/>

        </xsl:call-template>

    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, my function "parse":

```
<xsl:template name="parse">

    <!-- "a" is the text to parse -->
    <xsl:param name="a"/>

    <!-- return the value of "form" -->
    <xsl:value-of select="$a/@form"/>

</xsl:template>
```

**Now, my function "parse" isn't complete. I don't know how to replace the misspelled words by their "form" value.**

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you have both `<spelling>` and `<abrev>` or only one? They are not closing correctly in your source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you may have both `<abrev>` or `<spelling>` elements in your text (actually any one with a `form` attribute), and that your real XML is well-formed, this stylesheet can be used to replace the tagged text with the value in the `form` attribute:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates  select="messages/text"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text/*[@form]">
        <xsl:value-of select="@form"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you apply it to this input:

```
<messages>
    <text>
        <spelling form="Hello">Helo</spelling> I'll see you next <abrev form="week">wk</abrev> alright.
    </text>
    <text>
        <spelling form="Come on">cmon</spelling> get ready <abrev form="dude">dood</abrev>!
    </text>
</messages>
```

You will get this as output:

```
    Hello I'll see you next week alright.

    Come on get ready dude!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start with a identity template and from there create templates for each element so that you can control their specific output. So for example, have the `text` element output its text along with running the templates for the `spelling` and `abrev` elements, which output its `@form` attribute.

So that would look like the below.

```
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="messages">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="spelling">
    <xsl:value-of select="@form"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="abrev">
    <xsl:value-of select="@form"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: You could also use `<xsl:template match="spelling | abrev">` to remove duplication.

Comment: @helderdarocha Yeah I totally missed that until I saw your answer. Between the both of our answers they should be able to figure out what they want to do with it.